# Determine if given date is less than 1 day old, 1 to 3 days old, or more

Tags: php, datetime, if-statement, date-comparison

I need make if like --->

*if your activity is less than 1 day do something*

*else if your activity is more than 1 day and less than 3 do something else*

*else if your activity is more than 3 do something else*

I need this in PHP. My actual code is:

```
if (strtotime(strtotime($last_log)) < strtotime('-1 day') ) {
    $prom .= "" . json_encode('last_activity') . ": " . json_encode("inactive less than 1 day") . ",";
} else if (strtotime($last_log) > strtotime('-1 day') && strtotime($last_log) < strtotime('-3 day')) {
    $prom .= "" . json_encode('last_activity') . ": " . json_encode("inactive more than 1 day and less than 3 days") . ",";
} else if (strtotime($last_log) > strtotime('-3 day')) {
    $prom .= "" . json_encode('last_activity') . ": " . json_encode("inactive more than 3") . ",";
}
```

I think I really don't understand date calculations.

Comment: 1. Don't manually build json docs, I can't imagine what you think `json_encode()` is for, but it's for building the entire object. 2. Don't put relative data into files, put absolute data into files and let the decoding application do the math later, on demand. So: `json_encode(['last_activity' => $last_log])` returns `{"last_activity": "whatever"}` and be done with it.

Comment: What is the value of $last_log?  And why do strtotime twice in your first if...?

Comment: $last_log is datetime from DB .. because missclick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `date_diff` is much easier in this case (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php):

```
$datetime1 = date_create(); // now
$datetime2 = date_create($last_log);
    
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

// number of days between your last login and now
$days = $interval->format('%a');

// difference (only) in days
// (2023-11-05 and 2024-01-08 will return 3 because 05 and 08 are seperated by 3 days.
$days = $interval->format('%d');
```

For more formats see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Or in your way:

```
if (strtotime($last_log) < strtotime('-1 day')){
    // it's been longer than one day
}
```

Comment: @k4znlm: the answer is good in that it shows you how to use date_diff.  But I suggest that your logic also needs to be fixed.  The if statements like you did them, will always say "inactive for less than 1 day" for ALL values smaller than 1 day.  If you have the last log 5 days ago, your if (-5 < -1) will return true, and trigger that first condition.  But is should say "inactive for more than 3 days".

Comment: FYI, this did not work for me and just outputted "d", I had to change it to `$interval->format('%d days')` or `$interval->d`. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: @WesleySmith Thanks for noticing this, I added the %-sign to the argument in the format() function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with strtotime, do it like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('SOMETHING FOR YOU');

$last_log = '-0.5 day';

$last_log_time = strtotime($last_log);
$minus1day_time = strtotime('-1 day');
$minus3day_time = strtotime('-3 day');

echo $last_log_time . "<br>";
echo $minus1day_time . "<br>";
echo $minus3day_time . "<br>";

if ($last_log_time < $minus3day_time)
{
    echo "inactive more than 3";
}
elseif ( ($last_log_time <= $minus1day_time) && ($last_log_time >= $minus3day_time) )
{
    echo "inactive more than 1 day and less than 3 days";
}
elseif ($last_log_time > $minus1day_time)
{
    echo "inactive less than 1";
}
```

Couple things I changed from your code:

- remove the strtotime(strtotime()).  Do not do it twice!
- For your second if, I added parentheses to ensure correct evaluation of conditions.
- I reversed the order of your if.  First check if it is very old (so < -3).  Then check if it is between -3 and -1.  Then check between -1 and now.
- Added <= and >=.  The = cases were missing from your code.  So if the last_log was == -1, it was not processed ever.
- I replace "else if" by "elseif".
- I used variables because recalculating strtotime all over is wasteful.  And it makes the code less readable IMHO.

Then apply the json_encode comment.

To explain why the logic was reversed:

- the last login of a user will always be before now.
- lets say that the user's last_login is 5 days ago.  strtotime($last_login) will be smaller than strtotime('-1 days'), so the if will be true.  But that is not what the OP wants!  He wants here the case where the last login is older than 3 days.
- Remember that we are comparing numbers in the past, so the smaller, the older.

Comment: Yes, this is true, and i have mistake in my if logic. Thanks for explaning me that. I make my mystake in logic, because i cant see it in this. More better is use date_diff. I don't know about that function before :)

Answer (score 0):

Some modern advice using DateTime objects and `match()`.

For your scenario:

```
$UTC = new DateTime('midnight', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$daysPast = (int) $UTC->diff(new DateTime($last_log))->format('%r%a');
echo match (true) {
    $daysPast >   -1 => 'active',
    $daysPast === -1 => 'inactive less than 1 day',
    $daysPast >   -4 => 'inactive more than 1 day and less than 3 days',
    default          => 'inactive more than 3'
};
```

---

As a fuller demonstration with a battery of dynamic test dates: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Yi3rP))

```
$testPeriod = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('midnight -5 days', new DateTimeZone('UTC')),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime('midnight +2 days', new DateTimeZone('UTC')),
    DatePeriod::INCLUDE_END_DATE
);

$UTC = new DateTime('midnight', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
foreach ($testPeriod as $last_log) {
    // if $last_log is just a string, use: new DateTime($last_log)
    $daysPast = (int) $UTC->diff($last_log)->format('%r%a');
    printf(
        "\nComparing: %s versus %s (%d days past) : ",
        $UTC->format('Y-m-d'),
        $last_log->format('Y-m-d'),
        $daysPast
    );
    echo match (true) {
        $daysPast >   -1 => 'active',
        $daysPast === -1 => 'inactive less than 1 day',
        $daysPast >   -4 => 'inactive more than 1 day and less than 3 days',
        default          => 'inactive more than 3'
    };
}
```

Output:

```
Comparing: 2024-01-30 versus 2024-01-25 (-5 days past) : inactive more than 3
Comparing: 2024-01-30 versus 2024-01-26 (-4 days past) : inactive more than 3
Comparing: 2024-01-30 versus 2024-01-27 (-3 days past) : inactive more than 1 day and less than 3 days
Comparing: 2024-01-30 versus 2024-01-28 (-2 days past) : inactive more than 1 day and less than 3 days
Comparing: 2024-01-30 versus 2024-01-29 (-1 days past) : inactive less than 1 day
Comparing: 2024-01-30 versus 2024-01-30 (0 days past) : active
Comparing: 2024-01-30 versus 2024-01-31 (1 days past) : active
Comparing: 2024-01-30 versus 2024-02-01 (2 days past) : active
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$dateLog = new DateTime($last_log); // format if needed

$tomorrow     = new DateTime("tomorrow");
$yesterday    = new DateTime("yesterday");
$threeDaysAgo = new DateTime("-3 days");

if ($dateLog < $yesterday) {
        // Do what you want
} else if ($dateLog > $yesterday && $dateLog < $threeDaysAgo) {
        // Do another thing
} else if ($dateLog > $threeDaysAgo) {
        // ...
}
```

The doc is here : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: The OP made a mistake in his if statements logic as well.  So just changing to DateTime will not produce what he wants.